# spring activiti with load balancer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

We have just started developing few POC's on Spring Activiti as it is powerful in BPM workflow and we came up with one scenario which we do want to understand how spring activiti works with loadbalancer.

If suppose we have two servers, and that are balanced with load balancer.

Scenario:

- If one workflow has started in one server and how does the other server knows the workflow has started already or not.

workflow:
[image]

Could someone please help me in the above scenario.

Comment: activiti workflow is backed by a database where the workflow state is stored. So all the servers behind your load balancer should be talking to this database. Note that you can also have in memory db like h2 configured for activiti. In that case, one server will not be aware of the workflow started by other.

Comment: @yaswanth: In that case, you mean to say we don't need to worry where our workflow is running. Correct ?

Comment: Yes that’s correct.

Comment: Ok thank a million. I will try it and let you know.